# SQL trigger wont disable

Tags: sql, triggers

We had some problems awhile back where we had to make a trigger that wouldnt allow tables to be altered or dropped.

this is the trigger I made

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!' 
   ROLLBACK;
GO
```

Ok so this is no longer needed so I tried disabling the trigger with this command

```
DISABLE TRIGGER safety ON DATABASE;
GO
```

It completed without errors but it still didnt work I wasnt allowed to alter any tables and I get this error

```
You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Ok so I tried dropping the trigger all together, it worked the trigger is gone but the error is not. Only thing I can think of is that I put a copy of this trigger somewhere else and I cannot find it. I looked through all tables in the object explorer but cannot locate it.

anyone have any ideas how I move forward?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers`, `SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers`. Also, double check for stupid things like actually being on the wrong server -- `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Both sys.triggers and sys.server_triggers are empty.
Only have 1 server so that cant be the issue either. So it didnt help my issue though

Comment: Then there is no trigger, and you're on the wrong server or in the wrong database (not the one where `ALTER TABLE` is happening). When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

Comment: To put it differently: if, in the same Management Studio window, `DROP TRIGGER [safety]` gives an error that there is no such trigger, *and* an `ALTER TABLE` complains about the trigger, then the only possibility left is a permission issue that prevents you from seeing the trigger. But I suspect the `ALTER TABLE` would simply succeed. You're not using a `(localdb)`, by any chance, or anything else where it's really easy to be mistaken about what instance you're actually on?

Comment: Figured it out I used the generate script option and combed through it and found out where the dreaded trigger was haha. thanks

Comment: There you go. Sir Arthur Conan Doyle fixes another problem.